# Invalid type when trying to render component

Tags: reactjs, meteor, flow-router

I am trying to use FlowRouter and react-mounter in my Meteor React app but get the following error message:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object.

`client/main.html` has this div in body:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

with `client/main.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { App } from "/imports/ui/App";
import "/client/router";

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
});
```

`client/router.jsx` has this route:

```
import React from "react";
import { FlowRouter } from "meteor/ostrio:flow-router-extra";
import { mount, withOptions } from "react-mounter";

import App from "/imports/ui/App";
import Start from "/imports/ui/Start";

const mount2 = withOptions({
  rootId: "root"
}, mount);

FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: "Start",
  action() {
    console.log("start");
    mount2(App, {
      content: <Start />
    });
  }
});
```

`imports/ui/App.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";

export const App = ({content}) => {
  console.log("content", content);
  return <div>{content}</div>
};
```

content prints `undefined`.

and the `imports/ui/Start.jsx` component that I want to render:

```
import React from "react";

export const Start = () => (
  <div>
    start
  </div>
);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the imports in `/client/router.jsx` should have curly brackets like:

```
import { App } from "/imports/ui/App";
import { Start } from "/imports/ui/Start";
```